# If user changes the url and the wrong view is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state change callback which redirects to same state.

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toStateParams) {        
    if (toState.name != 'wsConnect') {
        console.log("change path!!");
        $location.path('/connect');                  

    }
  });
```

It works fine from start when a user opens new tab and enters a route with any url anchor. The user sees the view from the callback, but
if user changes manually the anchor and hits enter then
the callback works in half - anchor value is recovered but the user sees the view for his route not from the anchor.

If you reload the page the "bug" disappears.

I found a workaround:

```
    if (toState.name != 'wsConnect') {
        console.log("change path!!");
        $interval(function () {
          $state.go('wsConnect');
          $location.path('/connect');
        }, 1, 1);
    }
```

Comment: Please check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and enhance your answer so we can have a better idea of what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe consider using 
`$viewContentLoading` which fired once the view begins loading, before the DOM is rendered. The '$rootScope' broadcasts the event.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events

Comment: Thx, viewContentLoaded not Loading should be used. Plus I had to set the state in it manually also.